# Is there any way to make sure no duplicate items get added in firestore, I'm using Flutter and Firebase and I'm pretty new to this

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
   Future addCart() async{
     final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
     var currentUser = _auth.currentUser;
     CollectionReference _collectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users-cart- 
     items");
    return _collectionRef.doc(currentUser!.email).collection("items").doc().set(
      {
       "name": widget.name,
        "price": widget.price,
        "images": widget.image,
      }).then((value) => print("Added To Cart"));

     }
```

I'm using collectionReference and it does not have any .contain method to check if there are items of the same type already existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using collectionReference and it does not have any .contain method to check if there are items of the same type already existing

As you've already seen, there is no method present that can help you add a new document only if it doesn't already exists. So you have to check that yourself. This means that before performing the desired write operation, you have to check if that object (document) exists. If it doesn't, perform the write operation, otherwise, inform the user about the existence.

Comment: You're very welcome, Sandeep.